# LinearLayout larger than screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a horizontal `LinearLayout` which is wider than the screen of the device. It contains a `Button` which will move the layout to view the part outside the screen when it is clicked. The problem is that android is not creating the part outside the screen, so when I press the button, the view moves to show black screen where the remaining view should have been.

My code-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mScreenHeight;
    private int mScreenWidth;
    private LinearLayout mViewContainer;
    private View mTransparentContainer;
    private Button mSliderBtn;
    private View mSlidingView;
    private View mHomeView;
    private int mSlidingWidth;
    private boolean mIsSlidingMenuVisible = false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mScreenHeight = UserScreen.getHeight(mContext);
        mScreenWidth = UserScreen.getWidth(mContext);
        mSlidingWidth = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sliding_menu_offset) + 0.5f);

        mViewContainer = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        mViewContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mViewContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mScreenWidth + mSlidingWidth, mScreenHeight));
        setContentView(mViewContainer);

        LinearLayout homeContainer = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams homeContainerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mScreenWidth, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mHomeView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, homeContainer);
        mHomeView.setBackgroundColor(0x80ffffff);
        mViewContainer.addView(homeContainer, homeContainerParams);

        LinearLayout slidingContainer = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams slidingContainerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mSlidingWidth, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mSlidingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.slider_menu, slidingContainer);
        mViewContainer.addView(slidingContainer, slidingContainerParams);

        initUi();

        // other code
    }

    public void initUi() {
        mSliderBtn = (Button) mHomeView.findViewById(R.id.button_slider);
        mSliderBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTransparentContainer = mHomeView.findViewById(R.id.transparent_container);
        mTransparentContainer.setOnClickListener(this);

        // other code
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_slider:
            mSliderBtn.setEnabled(false);
            mIsSlidingMenuVisible = true;
            mTransparentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTransparentContainer.bringToFront();
            tableMoveLeft(mViewContainer, mSlidingWidth);
            break;
        case R.id.transparent_container:
            mSliderBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mIsSlidingMenuVisible = false;
            mTransparentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableMoveRight(mViewContainer, mSlidingWidth);
            break;
        // other cases
        }
    }

    // Animation Functions

    public void tableMoveLeft(final View container, final float newPos){
        ObjectAnimator moveLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(container, "translationX", 0, -newPos);
        moveLeft.setDuration(300);
        moveLeft.start();
    }

    public void tableMoveRight(final View container, final float newPos){
        ObjectAnimator moveRight = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(container, "translationX", -newPos, 0);
        moveRight.setDuration(300);
        moveRight.start();
    }

    // other code

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_menu"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <!-- other code -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_slider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:background="@drawable/move" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/transparent_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80800000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**slider_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_info_bg_popup"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Other Code -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Output on clicking the button**

[image: Output]

Using a `ScrollView` is not a solution because I dont want the user to freely scroll the view, and also there is a `ViewPager` in the main layout which will conflict with it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: so in your mTransparentContainer you want to have a layout in it?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is achieved here:
https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager

Even if you decide to implement it yourself, take a look in the code, there are some nice performance improvement tips. I used parts of it for a similar requirement.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No. I want to have the slider_menu layout in mSlidingView, but it is showing up black. I have indicated the region in the image. mTransparentContainer provides the reddish hue on the main layout which has been moved left. It is displaying properly.

Comment: @DanielAlexandrov The link points to a `ViewPager`, which is not what I want. First, I want the slide to happen on a button press and not a swipe. Second, it will pose the same problem as a `ScrollView`, it will interfere with the input of a `ViewPager` that I already have on the main screen. Also, android now officially provides a `ViewPager` in its sdk, and I would advice you to use that instead of the said library. It is also mentioned in their readme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android officially introduced sliding panel menu by introducing a newer concept called [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).  Most of the time Sliding Menu (`Navigation Drawer`) will be hidden and can be shown by swiping the screen from left edge to right or tapping the app icon on the action bar.

For example, the following layout uses a `DrawerLayout` with two child views: a `FrameLayout` to contain the main content (populated by a Fragment at runtime), and a `ListView` for the navigation drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

for additional info about `NavigationDrawer`, please take a look into these links :

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks, but I need to move the main layout as well. The Drawer will come over the main layout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the layout with size larger than screen size was set as the root container of the activity. I don't know what was the problem caused by that, but to fix it-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout rootContainer = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    setContentView(rootContainer);

    // other code

    rootContainer.addView(mViewContainer);
}
```

Any explanations of why having a root view larger than screen size created a problem are welcome :)